# Java Long won't print properly

Tags: java

This must be very silly but, I am trying to do the following:

```
long mult  = 2147483647 + 2147483647 + 2;
System.out.println(mult);  // result = 0
```

Now, my varaible `mult` would be a 10 digit number, well in the range of long. So I do not understand why it is printing out 0 as a result. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The arithmetic is being done with `int` instead of `long`, because the three constant values are `int`s. The fact that you're assigning to a `long` variable is irrelevant. Try this:

```
long mult  = 2147483647L + 2147483647L + 2L;
```

You could probably get away with making just one of the literals a long literal if you're careful - but I'd personally apply it to all of them, just to make it clear that you want `long` arithmetic for everything.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I did not know that my constants were being treated as integers

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
long mult = 2147483647L + 2147483647 + 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

thats because when you give any number directly like `num1 + num2` they are taken as integers and since the value is out of bounds in this case you will get either 0 or other output depending on the input.

You can easily resolve this by changing to

```
long mult  = 2147483647;
mult += 2147483647;
mult += 2;
System.out.println(mult);
```